# Types of CSS Layouts

Tags: css

I am a beginner and still cannot understand the types of layouts, the entire layout architecture for CSS. It seems trivial, but it is hard to search on the internet. All websites I've seen divide the CSS layouts in **Fixed**(or static), **Fluid** (or liquid) and **Responsive**. For instance, grids and flexbox are kind of aliens that appeared without categorization.

Here what I think it is:

**Responsive or Not Responsive** - Fixed and Fluid Layouts 
**Responsive by nature** - Grid-fixed layout, Grid-fluid, flexbox

Am I right? Can someone explain me the a valid categorization for our days?

Answer (score 7):

**Fixed** and **Fluid** web-page layouts pre-date the introduction of Responsive Layout methodology by a number of years.

Ten years ago and more (circa 2002-2005), when CSS2 positioning was already well supported by browsers but the majority of web-pages were still being laid out using `tables` and a `spacer.gif` (or two), choosing between a **Fixed** web-page layout (using hard-coded widths) and a **Fluid** web-page layout (using percentage-based widths) was a key design choice.

When Ethan Marcotte introduced the methodology for **Responsive Web Design** in [his seminal 2010 article in *A List Apart*](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design), this was a new approach: the idea that not only could page-widths expand and contract (as with **Fluid**), but that *individual page elements* might expand and contract independently from all others and (consequently) arrange themselves in horizontal rows or stack themselves vertically according to the interplay between their width and the width of the viewport on which they were being viewed.

Amongst other innovations, **Responsive** additionally enabled headings (and other textual elements) to have a changeable `font-size` and allowed elements like menus to toggle between being permanently visible in a sidebar to being initially invisible, made into visible drop-downs only when you tapped a menu button.

This made **Responsive** radically more sophisticated than the old **Fluid**.

A small number of even newer approaches followed, as alternatives or complements to **Responsive**.

One approach was named **Adaptive Web Design** (a term coined by Aaron Gustafson in 2011), which proposed, a small number (3-5) of predefined "snap-to" layouts in place of **Responsive** designs in which different elements might fluidly redraw themselves continuously with every pixel the `viewport-width` gained or lost.

Another approach (also 2011) was named **RESS** (*Responsive + Server Side* - a term coined by Luke Wroblewski) in which, depending on the viewport and / or device being used, certain elements would not just be hidden, but not even downloaded from the server.

**Flexbox** is distinct from the design methodologies and approaches above. It is a CSS3 module, intended to give designers more power over their 2-dimensional layouts and free them from the constraints and difficulties imposed by trying to 2-dimensionally position everything on the page using only the (limited) tool set of `margin`, `padding` and `float`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer was very much appreciated!